# Return the difference between two date time cells

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am placing Timestamps in column E and F using:

```
    function onEdit() {
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
       if( s.getName() == "Timesheet" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
      var r = s.getActiveCell();
       if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(-1, 5);
       if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 4);
       if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
    }
```

I would like to have the Time difference in hours between the two cells placed in column H(offset 7). I tried:

```
    var startTime = r.offset(-1, 4);
    var stopTime = r.offset(-1, 5);
    var totalTime = r.offset(-1, 7);
    var difTime = stopTime - startTime;
     totalTime.setValue(difTime);
```

But it's just giving me NaN.

Comment: make sure both the `startTime` and `stopTime` are in Date format

Comment: Tag as google apps script

Comment: Thanks. I will tag as app script not as app engine

Comment: please use the right tag : Google-Apps-Script , this will improve the chances of getting an appropriate answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the two lines as follows:

```
var difTime = stopTime - startTime;
    roundedDayes.setValue(difTime);
```

I think you were passing the wrong variable to setValue()

Comment: You were right about the one wrong variable but I also hadn't defined roundedDayes. Regardless It's still giving me an NaN. I edited to correct the wrong variable being used.

Comment: I also realized that I will need to run this function more often than I am running the timestamp function. The timestamps are editable and the total time needs to take this into account. I will have to rework this.

Answer (score 0):

make sure `startTime` and  `stopTime` are in Date format

Add this in your code.

```
var startTime = r.offset(-1, 4);
var stopTime = r.offset(-1, 5);
var totalTime = r.offset(-1, 7);
var difTime = stopTime - startTime;
var difHours = Math.floor(difTime / (3600 * 1000));
totalTime.setValue(difHours );
```

Comment: I have set the format to Date only, added your line of code, amended the setValue and it's still returning NaN. This is a timesheet for task that rarely take more than a day. The time is critical and there will be times when the time is edited after the fact (forgot to clock in, Changed projects without changing the timesheet, etc.). When that happens I will need the total time to update again. I think I will look at using simple google formulas and protecting the ranges. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is a working solution, I changed the offset values for my test to use simply start = colA, stop=col B and result in col C (or any other combination of 3 contiguous cells on the same row)

```
function test(){
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell();
  var startTime = new Date(r.offset(0, 0).getValue()).getTime();// get time in millisec
  Logger.log(startTime);
  var stopTime = new Date(r.offset(0, 1).getValue()).getTime();// get time in millisec
  Logger.log(stopTime);
  var totalTime = r.offset(0, 2); // define output range
  var difTime = stopTime - startTime; 
  var difHours = Math.floor(difTime / (3600 * 1000)); // do the math
  Logger.log(difTime);
  totalTime.setValue(difHours ); // and update result cell
}
```